# What does (define | :) mean in Inno Setup Preprocessor documentation conventions?

Tags: syntax, inno-setup, directive, preprocessor

I've been reading through Inno Setup preprocessor documentation and stumbled upon an expression `(define | :)` in the directive syntax documenting convention: (https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define)

```
(define | :) [private | protected | public] <ident> [[ <expr> ]] [[=] <expr>]
```

What does `(define | :)` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you can use either `define` or `:` with the same meaning. The `|` means *"or"* in syntax declarations.

So while commonly you would use:

```
#define AppName "My Program"
```

You can as well use:

```
#: AppName "My Program"
```

*Though, I've never seen the latter syntax in use until now.*

*Also note that the `|` does not necessarily mean that the two alternatives are equivalent. They typically are not (as is the case of `private | protected | public`). It's just in this particular case that they are.*